# Depth of Field issue

Tags: xna

I have converted a Depth Of Field shader from XNA 3.1 to 4.0.  The problem is, it is completely draining my colours and not rendering anything else.  You can see the problem here:

[Project Vanquish - Depth of Field issue](http://project-vanquish.co.cc/index.php)

Any ideas would be very grateful.

**EDIT**

I thought it best to add the Render method too:

```
public void PostProcess(GraphicsDevice device)
{
   // Gaussian Blur Horizontal
   device.SetRenderTarget(this.GaussianHRT);
   device.Clear(Color.White);
   device.SetRenderTarget(null);
   this.SetBlurEffectParameters(1.0f / this.device.Viewport.Width, 0);
   this.DrawQuad(this.resolveTarget, this.gaussianBlur.Effect);

   // Gaussian Blur Vertical
   device.SetRenderTarget(this.GaussianVRT);
   device.Clear(Color.White);
   device.SetRenderTarget(null);
   this.SetBlurEffectParameters(0, 1.0f / this.device.Viewport.Height);
   this.DrawQuad(this.GaussianHRT, this.gaussianBlur.Effect);

   // Render result
   device.Textures[0] = this.resolveTarget;
   device.Textures[1] = this.GaussianVRT;
   device.Textures[2] = this.depthRT;
   this.DrawQuad(this.resolveTarget, this.combine.Effect);

   // Reset RenderStates
   this.ResetRenderStates();
}
```

By outputting this to seperate RenderTargets, I can see some potential issues, but I can't understand why I get a blank RenderTarget even though I set the `resolveTarget RenderTarget` before I render all of the scene.  This is then rendered after the scene has been rendered.

Comment: Can you narrow it down (by setting the Combine pass to `tex2D(positionSampler)`, then `tex2D(blurSampler)` etc)? Is the depth-map and blur pass correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem existed in a function before this where I set the DepthBuffer.  Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

are you saying that you ported it line for line to xna 4 and it now exhibits this behavior, or did you make code changes? I mean, it looks to me like the pixel shader is just returning invalid color values.

can you give us some details about what changed in your shader from 3.1 -> 4 ?

*Edit:* To go down a different line of thought ... another reason that you'd see black rendering such as this is around lighting. I would double check and verify that all of your light parameters are being passed into the shader, and that they are calculating accordingly.

Comment: Sure.  I already had a PostProcessor in place and this works fine.  I then tried to implement the DoF but I get the invalid colors.  It should look like the image below the blurred one, but with the blurring working.

Comment: But I guess what I'm trying to say is that you made it seem like this worked previously under 3.1, but no longer works in 4.0. This suggests that some change was made in the "port". Am I understanding this correctly, or has this particular shader never worked ... I only ask because it changes the troubleshooting technique :-)

Comment: Ok, so on further investigation, becase the old XNA 3.1 code used a `BasicEffect`, they used `EnableDefaultLighting()`.  I can't use this as my `shader` is now a new class.

Answer (score 0):

You call DrawQuad function before setting the textures; this should result in invalid textures bound to Combine shader inputs.

There is a number of other things that can go wrong here, but this is the most likely suspect.

Comment: I have tried swapping these around and get nothing.  I am now rendering the stages out to seperate rendertargets to help with the debug process.